# Moving map content/ map signatures when zoom

Tags: leaflet, mobile

Got a problem with my leaflet map especially when using it on mobile devices.

When using the zoom (zoom in and out) my signatures are moving out of the screen. after finishing the zoom the signatures get their correct location.

is this the normal behavior of leaflet cuz of the layers? and how to fix this?

when adding a L.Marker f.e. for GPS location or for search results the marker doesnt move but is fixed on his position while zoom. would like to have the same behavior for my signatures.

signature = point signatures --> points --> in this case POIs

version of leaflet : 0.7.5

Comment: What is a "signature"? What version of Leaflet? Is there a reproducible example? Do you have any screenshots?

Comment: signature = point signatures --> points --> in this case POIs

version of leaflet : 0.7.5

Comment: Try Leaflet 1.0.2. The handling of markers and vector geometries when pinch-zooming has been revamped since the 0.7.x series.

Comment: @IvanSanchez, as you have given the accepted answer in comments, perhaps you could convert to a answer and claim the kudos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Leaflet 1.0.2. The handling of markers and vector geometries when pinch-zooming has been revamped since the 0.7.x series.